# Rails - sidekiq web interface show Forbidden when I try delete or post operations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, nginx, sidekiq

I have having issues with sidekiq web interface on my rails 5 app where I could not delete any of the jobs in the retry queue or perform any post operations. My research showed all signs having to do with an issue with SSL/https. I have nginx running on my production app with SSL

Answer (score 2):

The way I got this issue solved is adding a header in my nginx configuration. This is the line I added to the location block

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Full code looks like

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    # rest of code 
}
```

Adding this to my nginx configuration worked like a charm !! Hope this helps anyone having the same problem. Cheers!!